# Django REST: serialize url to list of objects of a category

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

Hard facts: 
I am using Django 2.0 with python 3.6, if it makes any difference.

What I am trying to achieve is a link to a list of objects that belong to a summary. 
I have a ManyToOne relationship in my models.py.

```
class Summary(models.model):
  type=models.CharField

class Object(models.Model):
  summary= models.ForeignKey(Summary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

in urls.py

```
object_list= views.ObjectListViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list'
})
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'^summary/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/objects/$', object_list, name='summary-objects')
])
```

and now the idea was to give a user the possibility to click the an url in the browsable API and getting all objects.
So, I tried to write a MethodField in serializers.py. I am not able to get any reasonable URL here, the only solution would be to hardcode it.

```
class SummarySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name="app:summary-detail")

    objects= serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_obj_url')

    def get_obj_url(self, obj):
        pass

    class Meta:
        model = Summary
```

Is this possible? 
Is it necessary to write a MethodField?
If yes, how do I get the url I need?

Comment: rest framework has a special reverse that will return absolute url including header, domain. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, reverse, as suggested in the comments, does the trick. 
The solution is:

```
def get_obj_url(self, obj):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('api-root')) + 'summary/{id}/objects'.format(
        id=obj.id)
```

EDIT:Typo